# Expandable list view item button pressed changes value in all list view items

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to increase the value of particular item after pressing the increment button which is inside expandable list view but it affects in all of list view items of sub category name value.

Here is some code I came up with. i dont know where i've made the mistake even though its in statefulwidget. suggestions are welcome. any idea..?

[the screenshot of my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQchc.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class SubService extends StatefulWidget {
  String strCatId;
  SubService({Key key, @required this.strCatId}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  SubServiceState createState() => new SubServiceState(strCatId);
}

class SubServiceState extends State<SubService> {
  List lessons; 
  List data;
  SubService sModel;
  RestDatasource api = new RestDatasource();
  int _n = 0;

  var subService = new List<SubServices>();
  String strCatId;

  void add() {
    setState(() {
      _n++;
    });
  }

  void minus() {
    setState(() {
      if (_n != 0) _n--;
    });
  }

  SubServiceState(String strCatId) {
    strCatId = strCatId;
    RestDatasource.getSubServices(strCatId).then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        subService = list.map((model) => SubServices.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Sub services'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: subService == null ? 0 : subService.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return new ExpansionTile(
            title: new Text(
              subService[i].getsubcategoryName,
            ),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                 children: _buildExpandableContent(subService[i].getsubService),
                  // BottomAppBar(child: Text('Bottom bar'),),

                ),

            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildExpandableContent(List<Subservicename> sub) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (Subservicename content in sub)
      columnContent.add(
        new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                 Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
               child : Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 40),
                  child: Text(
                    content.getsubservicename,
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                ),
                 ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 40),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 25.0,
                    child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: minus ,
                      child: new Icon(
                        const IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: 15.0,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 40),
                  child: new Text('$_n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 40),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 25.0,
                    child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: add,
                      child: new Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 15.0),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    return columnContent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ejabu approach, I modified it to fit my needs. i need to add my counter in my Subservicename model and increase it in there.

to add product

```
_addProduct(int index) {
setState(() {
  content.getcounter++;
});
```

to display the value

```
child : new Text('${content.getcounter}',
```

and the same for remove product.

```
onPressed: () => setState((){ if (content.getcounter != 0) content.getcounter--;}),
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you actually only have one integer as reference that defined in SubServiceState

```dart
class SubServiceState extends State<SubService> {
  List lessons; 
  ...

  int _n = 0; // you only have one _n
```

In spite of building columnContent programmatically, the app will always look for **one `memory address`** of variable _n.

```dart
for (Subservicename content in sub)
      columnContent.add(
        new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,

              ...
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 40),
                child: new Text('$_n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              ),
```

#### Solution

1. You need to move all widget inside columnContent.add() to a new Stateful Widget. Then each of them has its own reference of _n property. or ..
2. Change int _n to another type, maybe `List<Map>` or `Map<List>` which corresponds to your payload structure

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll see if this gets me where I want to be. :)